# Accepting Multiple Strings in 2 dimensional array?

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array

While executing this, loop is directly jumping to the end and giving me below output.

```
1.Generate Bill

2.Generate Bills of last 10 Purchase

Select Option:1

Enter Number of Groceries:3

Enter GroceryName:XYZ <Hit Enter>

Enter GroceryName:

Enter GroceryName:
```

Could you please suggest me better way of doing it in c ?
I have already tried certain links on stack overflow on this, however it doesn't seem to be working for me.

```
void main()
{
    int iPrice[1000];
    char cGroceName[100][100];
    int iOption;
    int iGrocNum;

    printf("\n1.Generate Bill");
    printf("\n2.Generate Bills of last 10 Purchase");
    printf("\nSelect Option:");
    scanf_s("%d", &iOption);

    switch (iOption)
    {
    case 1:
        printf("\nEnter Number of Groceries:");
        scanf_s("%d",&iGrocNum);
        for (int i = 0; i <iGrocNum; i++)
        {  

            printf("\nEnter GroceryName:");
            scanf_s(" %s",cGroceName[i]);

        }
```

Comment: And what exactly is the question? Something is not working properly or what? Note: you didn't posted whole source code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
scanf_s(" %s",cGroceName[i]);
```

should be

```
scanf_s("%99s", cGroceName[i], sizeof cGroceName[i]);
```

as `scanf_s` requires a third argument for certain format specifiers such as `%s` denoting the maximum size of its corresponding argument.

See [`scanf_s` documentation](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#K.3.5.3.4).

Comment: Don't direct to a vendor-specific page for standard functions. Either use a neutral site, or - better - the standard. There is also no use specifying the max. length, when using `scanf_s`, as that already takes the max. length of the array.

Comment: Okay. Linked to the `scanf_s` part of the C11 draft. As for the other thing, I assume you're talking about the width specification and the third argument? Both aren't the same. The width specification ensures that 99 (in this case) characters are written into the buffer (`cGroceName[i]`) when the input consist of more than 99  characters instead of leaving it empty. Quoting from [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w40768et.aspx): "_If no width specification field is used, and the token read in is too big to fit in the buffer, nothing is written to that buffer_"

Comment: Only twist is the C11 standard doesn't adopt the `_s` variants but leaves it up to compilers to support. Not a critique at all, just good to advise that `_s` isn't actually part of the standard library, and is only guaranteed to be available if `__STDC_LIB_EXT1__` is defined by the implementation and if the user defines `__STDC_WANT_LIB_EXT1__` to the integer constant `1` before including `<stdio.h>`.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: The _bounds checking interface_ functions are very well part of the standard! The standard just say they optional. The reason for requiring a macro to enable them, might be the Microsoft C library, which provides functions with the same name, but (part of them) have different signatures.

Comment: Well, I agree with what you are saying, and that is what I, perhaps inartfully, attempted to explain in my comment. The standard recognizes the `_s` variants, but does not mandate their inclusion in the standard library.